# checkboxes are not appearing in browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable_users">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row" class="heading">
            <th class="table-checkbox" align="center" style="padding-right:0px;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" id="checkAll" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.NotificationRecord)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes chk" value="@item.GCMRegistrationId" name="SelectedAdmissions"/>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jquery for above checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#checkAll').click(function (event) {  
        if (this.checked) { 
            $('.chk').each(function () { 
                $('.checker span').addClass('checked');
                this.checked = true;  
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.chk').each(function () { 
                this.checked = false; 
                $('.checker span').removeClass('checked');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I am running my code in Chrome or in Mozilla, the checkboxes are not appearing but they are there: When I check in **inspect element** I can see that they are there but they are hidden.
How can I solve this?

Comment: check your css - @Dolly Gupta

Comment: Just noticed this problem on my website. Haven't changed any code, but the checkboxes aren't rendering on my PC. They show up on my Mac, but that may be because my Mac isn't on the latest version of Chrome

Comment: Update: On my PC, the checkboxes show up in Edge, but not Chrome (don't know about Firefox). The checkboxes are missing on my Android too (also running Chrome). I'm guessing this is a Chrome bug.

Comment: manwill, can you give me a link to your site please (where can i see the problem?). Which chrome's version do you use? Have you seen the same here https://jsfiddle.net/gpLzo60v/3/ ?

Answer (score 0):

hm... if you want to check if checkbox is checked, you should do this:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

if you want to change checkbox's value, you should do this:

```
$(this).prop(':checked', true)
```

Comment: The question isn't about whether it's checked. The problem is that the checkboxes aren't showing up at all (checked or unchecked).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,
I gave CSS to my class and now checkboxes are appering in Chrome and  Mozilla both.`enter code here`

```
 div.checker input[type=checkbox] {
        opacity: 1 !important;
        -moz-appearance: checkbox !important;
        -webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;
         width:15px;
    }
```